# Left 1000 records from delete 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, oracle11g, sql-delete

Table is huge. For testing application I want to delete all, except 1000 records from table. 1000 lucky records don't have identifier that can given as:

```
DELETE FROM HUGE_TABLE t WHERE t.IDENTIFIER!='LUCKY'
```

What is best way in one sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count the numberOfRecordsOnYourDB and do:

```
set ROWCOUNT  (numberOfRecordsOnYourDB - 1000 )
delete from hugetable
Go
```

This will delete records from your table but stop processing after the specified number of rows.

oh and don't forget to set the ROWCOUNT back to a big value, or just open a new connection to do the other tasks

Comment: That looks like SQL Server syntax...?

Comment: Wasn't the question for Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE HUGE_TEST AS
  SELECT * FROM HUGE_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;
```

Now you can either use this for testing, or delete your original table and rename this table to actual table name.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new temp table TempHugeTable
- Insert lucky records into TempHugeTable (Or rename TempHugeTable into HugeTable, but take care of indexes and other stuff like that)
- Truncate HugeTable (Or Delete it)

This is the fastest ways to deal with huge amount of data, works also when you have to update only a small amount in a huge table.

Answer (score 1):

To give you another option of true randomness, you could try this:

```
DELETE FROM huge_table
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM huge_table
    ORDER BY dbms_random.value
  ) WHERE rownum <= 1000
)
```

But I agree with other answers that truncating and avoiding ordering is going to be a lot faster